# Remove string character after run of n characters in string

Tags: python, string

Suppose you have a given string and an integer, n. Every time a character appears in the string more than n times in a row, you want to remove some of the characters so that it only appears n times in a row. 
 For example, for the case n = 2, we would want the string 'aaabccdddd' to become 'aabccdd'. 
 I have written this crude function that compiles without errors but doesn't quite get me what I want:

```
def strcut(string, n):
    for i in range(len(string)):
        for j in range(n):
            if i + j < len(string)-(n-1):
                if string[i] == string[i+j]:
                    beg = string[:i]
                    ends = string[i+1:]
                    string = beg + ends
    print(string)
```

These are the outputs for strcut('aaabccdddd', n):

| n | output | expected |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 'abcdd' | 'abcd' |
| 2 | 'acdd' | 'aabccdd' |
| 3 | 'acddd' | 'aaabccddd' |

I am new to python but I am pretty sure that my error is in line 3, 4 or 5 of my function. Does anyone have any suggestions or know of any methods that would make this easier?

Comment: can string character can be in any order ? or you want to remove continous characters ? is the order is same as alphabets in a string ?

Comment: A few things I noticed. Don't update string if that is you data source and your output. You are modifying it while still trying to use it as the original string to look through. Also, there doesn't seem to be anything in place that will reset n if I am starting a new section of letters from string. All the code does now is for each element in string, see if the the next 'n' elements match. If they do pop them in. A conceptually simpler solution could be break up the string into a list of different characters, then trim each row to 'n' and append them all back.

Comment: @sahasrara62 Letters can be in any order in the input but I want the output string to be in the same order otherwise. So for n=2, 'dddcczaaa' -> 'ddcczaa'

Comment: so what will be the output for n=2 stirng='aaabbcdaaacccdsdsccddssse'

Comment: @sahasrara62 i would want n=2 stirng='aaabbcdaaacccdsdsccddssse' to go to 'aabbcdaaccdsdsccddsse'

Comment: Regex? `return re.sub(fr"(.)\1{{{n-1},}}", r"\1"*n, string)`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp that's OP solution dude, you should add it as an answer

Comment: How are people this good at regex lol

Comment: @sahasrara62 It may be _an_ answer, but probably not helpful to OP who is a professed beginner - which is why I didn't post an answer.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp  probably not helpful to OP now, but it will be helpful for other people and add a new perspective to solve problems in other ways also.. for the future developers .. add this solution :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can implement a `stack` data structure.

Idea is you add new character in stack, check if it is same as previous one or not in stack and yes then increase counter and check if counter is in limit or not if yes then add it into stack else not. if new character is not same as previous one then add that character in stack and set counter to 1

```
# your code goes here
def func(string, n):
    stack = []
    counter = None
    for i in string:
        if not stack:
            counter = 1
            stack.append(i)
        elif stack[-1]==i:
            if counter+1<=n:
                stack.append(i)
                counter+=1
        elif stack[-1]!=i:
            stack.append(i)
            counter = 1
        
    return ''.join(stack)
print(func('aaabbcdaaacccdsdsccddssse', 2)=='aabbcdaaccdsdsccddsse')
print(func('aaabccdddd',1 )=='abcd')
print(func('aaabccdddd',2 )=='aabccdd')
print(func('aaabccdddd',3 )=='aaabccddd')
```

output

```
True
True
True
True
```

Answer (score 2):

This may not answer why your code does not work, but here's an alternate solution using regex:

```
import re
def strcut(string, n):
    return re.sub(fr"(.)\1{{{n-1},}}", r"\1"*n, string)
```

How it works: First, the pattern formatted is `"(.)\1{n-1,}"`. If `n=3` then the pattern becomes `"(.)\1{2,}"`

- (.) is a capture group that matches any single character
- \1 matches the first capture group
- {2,} matches the previous token 2 or more times

The replacement string is the first capture group repeated `n` times

For example: `str = "aaaab"` and `n = 3`. The first "a" is the capture group `(.)`.  The next 3 "aaa" matches `\1{2,}` - in this example `a{2,}`. So the whole thing matches `"a" + "aaa" = "aaaa"`. That is replaced with "aaa".

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/K9GjuY/1/) can explain it better than me.

Answer (score 1):

The method I would use is creating a new empty string at the start of the function and then everytime you exceed the number of characters in the input string you just not insert them in the output string, this is computationally efficient because it is `O(n)` :

```
def strcut(string,n) :

    new_string = ""
    first_c, s = string[0], 0

    for c in string :

        if c != first_c :
            first_c, s= c, 0

        s += 1
        if s > n : continue
        else : new_string += c 

    return new_string

print(strcut("aabcaaabbba",2))  # output : #aabcaabba
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply, to anwer the question

> appears in the string more than n times **in a row**

the following code is small and simple, and will work fine :-)

```
def strcut(string: str, n: int) -> str:
    tmp = "*" * (n+1)
    for char in string:
        if tmp[len(tmp) - n:] != char * n:
            tmp += char
    print(tmp[n+1:])

strcut("aaabccdddd", 1)
strcut("aaabccdddd", 2)
strcut("aaabccdddd", 3)
```

Output:

```
abcd
aabccdd
aaabccddd
```

**Notes:**

The character `"*"` in the line `tmp = "*"*n+string[0:1]` can be any character **that is not in the** `string`, it's just a placeholder to handle the start case when there are no characters.

The `print(tmp[n:])` line simply removes the `"*"` characters added in the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need nested loops.  Keep track of the current character and its count.  include characters when the count is less or equal to n, reset the current character and count when it changes.

```
def strcut(s,n):
    result = ''                           # resulting string
    char,count  = '',0                    # initial character and count
    for c in s:                           # only loop once on the characters
        if c == char: count += 1          # increase count
        else:         char,count = c,1    # reset character/count
        if count<=n:  result += c         # include character if count is ok
    return result
```

Comment: Nice. upvote for the detail explanations.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give some ideas, this is a different approach. I didn't like how n was iterating each time even if I was on i=3 and n=2, I still jump to i=4 even though I already checked that character while going through n. And since you are checking the next n characters in the string, you method doesn't fit with keeping the strings in order. Here is a rough method that I find easier to read.

```
def strcut(string, n):
    for i in range(len(string)-1,0,-1): # I go backwards assuming you want to keep the front characters
        if string.count(string[i]) > n:
            string = remove(string,i)
    print(string)

def remove(string, i):
    if i > len(string):
        return string[:i]
    return string[:i] + string[i+1:]

strcut('aaabccdddd',2)
```